# all commands of group should be successful or none

Tags: linux, bash

I am testing following scenario: Either both commands should succeed or none.

Example: Let's assume there is file `abc` but there's no file `xyz`. And there are commands:

```
mv abc bcd   # abc exists and gets renamed to bcd. But I want this to fail
             # as well since command below is going to fail.

mv xyz yza   # xyz doesn't exist, so this will fail.
```

How to achieve this kind of atomicity in bash?

Comment: use `&&` between commands. this will guarantee that the next command is executed only if the previous command succeeds

Comment: I think there will be a problem: mv abc bcd, will successfully rename abc. but next command will fail as xyz doesn't exist. So I want previous command (mv abc bcd). to be undone.

Comment: There isn't a direct way to do this. There are a few different ways to fake it, but they depend on the specifics of the commands you want to execute, and I don't think any are really bulletproof. What's the actual goal here, and is there another way to achieve it?

Answer (score 1):

You can't really do that because move is destructive. You would have to copy both files and then, if successful, delete the originals, otherwise delete the new ones.

Comment: Instead of a copy you may be able to get away with `ln`, which is much cheaper.

Comment: @melpomene well, yes, ln is cheaper, but you are testing the copy which may fail if the target doesn't have space, for example.

Answer (score 1):

Testing the existance of file `xyz` will not help: you might miss the rights to write to `yza`.First copy both files and delete the originals when both copies worked can fail too. Another program might have been waiting for `bcd` and start some processing before your rollback.
You can try something with a tmp directory:

```
rollback() {
   mv ${tmpdir}/bcd abc
   mv ${tmpdir}/yza xyz
   rm -r ${tmpdir}
   echo "action failed"
   exit
}

tmpdir=/tmp/movetwo
mkdir ${tmpdir} || exit

cp abc ${tmpdir}/bcd || rollback 
cp xyz ${tmpdir}/yza || rollback
rm abc ${tmpdir}/bcd || rollback 
rm xyz ${tmpdir}/yza || rollback
cp ${tmpdir}/bcd bcd || rollback 
cp ${tmpdir}/yza yza || rollback
rm -r ${tmpdir}
```

This can still go wrong in different ways (after `abc` has been removed, some other process fills up the free disk space, permissions changed, ...)

You can try something like this with

```
# check bcd and yza not exist, code can not handle that
test -f bcd && { echo "nope"; exit 1; }
test -f yza && { echo "nope"; exit 1; }

# optional other tests: you can delete abc xyz, other tests...
ln abc bcd && ln xyz yza && rm abc xyz

#cleanup when moving abc failed
test -f abc && { mv yza xyz; rm bcd; }

#cleanup when moving xyz failed
test -f xyz && { mv bcd abc; rm yza; }
```